# Dlib failing to install

Tags: python, pip, dlib

I am trying to install Dlib-19.24.0 for a facial recognition project because facial_recognition needs it to work. When I first started trying to install Facial recognition I thought, "Oh, an error? let me see" but it just let me down a rabbit hole of forums and repositories. I'm on 3.11 and Windows 10 (I refuse to install 11).

Here is two pieces of the output it gave when trying to install any of the ways listed below. The total output is too long (about 560,000 characters) so I picked out the ending and the first part of the error message.

First part:

```
running install
C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing tools/python\dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\cmake_utils\*\build*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\setup.py:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
Building extension for Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\python.exe -DDLIB_GIF_SUPPORT=no -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -A x64'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32215.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32215.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/asdon/Adeel/python.exe (found version "3.11.1")
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/asdon/Adeel/libs/Python311.lib
-- pybind11 v2.2.4
-- Using CMake version: 3.25.2
-- Compiling dlib version: 19.24.0
-- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
-- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Enabling AVX instructions
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
-- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
-- DID NOT FIND CUDA
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/asdon/Downloads/dlib-19.24.0/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-311/Release
Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- /m'
MSBuild version 17.5.0+6f08c67f3 for .NET Framework
```

Last part:

```
C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\include\dictobject.h(22,24): message : see declaration of 'PyDict_GetItem' (compiling source file C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\tools\python\src\gui.cpp) [C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\build\temp.win
-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(1894,33): message : while trying to match the argument list '()' (compiling source file C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\tools\python\src\gui.
cpp) [C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 108, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 74, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 123, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 164, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 150, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1221, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\setup.py", line 134, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\setup.py", line 174, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

All between that is just lines nearly repeating, just changing the include file name:

> C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\dlib\external\pybind11\include\pybind11/pybind11.h(1895,30): error C2027: use of undefined type '_frame' (compiling source file
> C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\tools\python\src\gui.cpp)
> [C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
>
> C:\Users\asdon\Adeel\include\pytypedefs.h(22,16): message : see
> declaration of '_frame' (compiling source file
> C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\tools\python\src\gui.cpp)
> [C:\Users\asdon\Downloads\dlib-19.24.0\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]

I'm using pip to install in all my **attempts:**:

- I tried downloading the Tar.gz from pypi: Same result.
- Next, I uninstalled Setuptools, Cmake, Microsoft C++ build tools and reinstalled all of them (such a pain): Same result.
- Next, I tried cloning the github: Same result.
- Next, I tried downgrading my python (PAIN) and getting an uploaded wheel: Same result.
- Next, I tried using the `--pep-517` protocol: Same result.
- My last attempt, using `setup.py`, I installed it with the prefix `--no-DLIB-GIF-SUPPORT`: Same result.

Comment: @MarceloPaco I don't believe this post needs a minimum reproducible example because it's working with library installation. This does not need code for obvious reasons. This is all in the command line.